# Как из переменной типа String записать в файл

Tags: c++builder, c++

```
FMessageHTMLFile(String Message, int WhoSent)
{   
    ofstream foutFile("Chat.html", ios_base::app);
//  foutFile << "<p id='My'>"+Message+"</p>";
    foutFile << Message;
    foutFile.close();
}
```

Помогите мне с такой проблемой.

Нужна значение и переменной типа string записать в файл. Как это сделать?

У меня ругается на строку

```
foutFile << Message;
```

Заранее Спасибо!

Comment: А что такое `String` с большой буквы? Если это строка, почему не `std::string`?

Comment: ЗЫ: подумайте на досуге, как устроены перегруженные операторы в С++ и почему `"<p id='My'>"+Message+"</p>"` не скомпилируется.

Comment: Вот изменил но результат тот же
 std::string a = "dsvvsdv";
 ofstream foutFile("Chat.html", ios_base::app);
 foutFile << a;
 foutFile.close();

Comment: эээ... а что именно говорит компилятор? вы не забыли случайно

    #include <string>

Comment: >ЗЫ: подумайте на досуге, как устроены перегруженные операторы в С++ >и почему "<p id='My'>"+Message+"</p>" не скомпилируется.
А причем здесь эта строка если она закоментирована

Comment: Большое спасибо    
подключил эту библиотеку все заработало а я пол дня голову ломал   #include <string>

Comment: bcc32? Может быть, вы используете допотопную версию компилятора? Попробуйте добавить

    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

в начало файла; если не сработает, (1) выкиньте антиквариат и воспользуйтесь нормальным компилятором, (2) тем временем напишите

    foutFile << a.c_str();

(авось да сработает).

Comment: Использую среду разработки    
Embarcadero® C++Builder® XE Version 15.0.3953.35171    
Заработало когда добавил #include <string>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё очень просто.
В билдере используется свой собственный стринг и для него не перегружены  операторы **>>** и **<<** 
называется он `String` (с большой буквы)
это точно касается C++ builder 6 (что в XE незнаю)

для вывода можно использовать **`<< Message.c_str()`** а вот с вводом будут заморочки...

---

что касается `string (std::string)` то для его работы требуется заголовок `#include <string>` и стринг с маленькой небудет работать с объектами из билдера

тоесть **`String != string`**

---

откуда эта хрень? ("String")

как я понял `String` это обёртка стринга из делфи, но я не проверял так что не буду претендовать на истину в первой инстанции...

Comment: При использовании c_str() выводит адрес.  

    String Test;
    Test = "GHbbdd";
    ofstream foutFile("Chat.html");
    foutFile << Test.c_str();
    foutFile.close(); // закрываем файл

В файл списывает адрес пр. 15a329c ...

Comment: ну в чём проблема разыменовать? *(Test.c_str())  

звёздочка это оператор разыменования, то есть он возьмёт адрес и перейдёт по этому адресу